# How should I display scientific and non-scientific functions at the university on my email signature?

Tags: job, titles

I am an Associate Professor at a British University who also has a function as Coordinator for a research team.

Should my signature and business card be:

> Assoc. Prof. Dr. T. Koznin (? Assoc. Prof. T. Kozin, PhD)
>
> Cöordinator, A Research Team
>
> University of Pleasure

Or:

> Dr. T. Koznin
>
> Associate Prof., Faculty of Cheesecake
>
> Cöordinator, A Research Team
>
> University of Pleasure

I wonder:

- Is it strange or redundant to have "Assoc. Prof." before Dr.?

Comment: Which of those rows is the "non-scientific function"?

Comment: "Coordinator", @FedericoPoloni , although it involves science, it's also political/bureucratic

Answer (score 4):

Normally, someone from administration will have guidelines on the writing and layout of official university stationary, which normally includes business cards. You should check with your departmental clerical staff about these [rules and procedures; you may not have freedom in this area](http://www.exeter.ac.uk/staff/employment/academicroles/youteach/ap_(e&s)/usingthetitleassociateprofessor/), and end up with a print order that must be destroyed. There are often policies on email signature on official addresses also. You need to appreciate the magnitude of the bureaucracy that steers the leviathan of a UK university.

That said, you are confusing your hired position with your titles. They are different. A professor, of any kind (Emeritus, Full, etc) normally just uses the title of Professor. The nature of your appointment Associate Professor for a research group is not part of your nominal titles. It also depends on whether your name is used in a context where full academic attributions are also used. Pre-nominal titles do not compound in the UK as they do in the Germanic style, (except in certain circumstances), however we do tend to list all qualifications, not just postgraduate ones.

Simple style:

> Prof. T. Koznin
>   Associate Professor of Hard Maths
>   University of Blogshire

Fully Qualified:

> Prof. T. Koznin, BSc, MSc, PhD
>   Associate Professor of Hard Maths
>   University of Blogshire

An example of extreme compounding titles:

> Eur Ing Prof Sir J Cholmondley-Warner BSc PhD MRCP MRSE CBE
>   Emeritus Professor of Fine Whining
>   Faculty of Laggards
>   University of Midshires

I just gave the last one to illustrate how complicated the rules of formal correct academic titling can be here (and I did not choose an academic Peer - that was even too complicated for me).

---

<sub>Footnote for UK academics: Some institutions have taken to using the title *Associate Professor* for Grade 9 posts which at other institutions are graded as *Senior Lecturer* or *Reader*. They feel it enhances their ability to attract research staff from abroad who do not understand our grading system in order improve their REF. Its a way of attracting contributors without paying the Grade 10 professorial scale.</sub>